# Pass value from executed JScript to Batch File

Tags: batch-file, jscript

I have tried many different keywords such `Echo`, `return`, `print`, `WScript.echo()` etc.. and am unable to find a way to return a value from a `js` file to a `bat` file.

A simplified version of my `bat` file would be a simple call to a `js` file and prints based on the returned `ERRORLEVEL`

```
"myfile.js" 

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Warnings
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO Success
:Warnings
ECHO Warning
GOTO End

:Success
ECHO Success
```

My `JScript` file does what I need it to do, and stores a Error count in a var:

```
.
.
.    
var errorCount = tci.GetLastResultDescription().ErrorCount);
```

My objective is to return a status telling me if there is an error, so essentially, all I want to do is something along the lines of:

```
if (errorCount>0)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

However, naturally, If does not work this easily. Is there a way to pass a value back to the `bat` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You could use

```js
WSH.Quit(tci.GetLastResultDescription().ErrorCount);
```

... which will make `cscript` exit with an errorlevel of the errorcount.  If you prefer a boolean exit status, then

```js
WSH.Quit(tci.GetLastResultDescritpion().ErrorCount ? 1 : 0);
```

You could also pass it as a string using `WSH.Echo`, but that requires executing `cscript` within a `for /f` loop to capture the output.  I'd use `WSH.Quit(n)` if I were you.

---

For what it's worth, batch + JScript work extremely well in a hybrid format.  You could combine myfile.js and myfile.bat into one hybrid.bat script.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" && (
    >&2 echo exit status was 0
) || (
    >&2 echo exit status was non-zero
)

goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

WSH.Quit(Math.round(Math.random()));
```

See [David Ruhmann's demo Gist](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433) for more examples.

Comment: Beautiful! `WSH` is something I should have read into! Also, I will take a look at combining them into a hybrid format, as this will reduce the number of files required! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `WSH` is a shorthand alias for `WScript`.  `WScript` is the name of the global context.  Where JavaScript uses the `window` or `document` object for most of its methods, JScript uses the `WScript` object.  `WSH.Quit(n)`, `WSH.Echo(str)`, `WSH.StdErr.WriteLine(str)`, etc.